# Skype: How to record a podcast?

Tags: windows, skype, audio-recording, podcasts

I am doing a podcast with some friends. We are planning to do this by getting onto a Skype conference call and discussing our topic.

Is there a way to record this Skype conference conversation into a MP3?

(The OS is Windows XP.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [CallGraph](http://callgraph.biz/).  It is free and easy to use.  Plus you can configure it to record the two halves of the conversation on different channels (left and right) which makes editing easier.  They have actually had very responsive support (free) when I have had questions too.

[Pamela](http://www.pamela.biz/) is a little better, but more expensive, unless you only want to record really short pieces.

**Update:** I've actually switched to Pamela Professional now. I was having some odd sound quality issues with CallGraph and their support (yes, a free program with actual support) wasn't able to help me resolve it. Pamela has its own problems though, like occasionally not recording anything.

Comment: Pamela is just so much more polished and works out of the box. With CallGraph you gotta restart Skype and it just looks wonky... Should you get Pamela professional or will Pamela call recorder suffice?

Comment: @drozzy - Without Pamela Professional you are limited to really short recordings. I actually use Pamela Professional now and really like it. I started having recording quality issues with CallGraph. Although Pamela has its own headaches (like occasionally just not recording even when it says it is.)

Answer (score 8):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) should do the job

See:

- [Record a phone conversation with Skype](http://weblogs.asp.net/jasonsalas/archive/2005/05/03/405334.aspx)
- [Recording Skype call - can you help?](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexbarn/archive/2005/03/01/383359.aspx)

Comment: Could you elaborate how to use Audacity to record?

Comment: I've added a few links

Comment: There seems to be no definite guide on howto of skype+audacity. Most of the links are outdated...

Comment: Seems Pamela call recorder has a limit of 15minutes on recordings, whereas Pro version is unlimited http://www.pamhelp.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&group=pamela&group=pamela&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=105&nav=0

Answer (score 2):

There's also [G-Recorder](http://www.g-recorder.com) plugin for Skype:

- records Skype calls automatically saves them to your mailbox and/or
  to disk
- saves chat history along with call recordings in view of
  conversations
- has free edition

*Disclaimer: I'm a co-author of G-Recorder*

Answer (score 1):

[Free Video Call Recorder for Skype](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-Video-Call-Recorder-for-Skype.htm) can be used to perform this task. Besides it is absolutely free and you can record the calls as long as you need it.